# 301 redirects or rewriting using web.config

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, asp-classic, web-config

I need to configure rewriting to redirect two classic asp dynamic files to 2 diferents asp files:

```
example.com/file.asp?id=100        => example.com/file.asp?id=200
example.com/file.asp?id=100&bc=no  => example.com/file.asp?id=200&bc=no
```

I'm not an expert I've been looking for the answer but all the suggestions points to `.htaccess` and I have hosted my site in windows server.

So, I understand that I have to configure my `web.config` to rewrite.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

From the example you have given it doesn't look like you are redirecting to a different file, just modifying the querystring parameters.

if you are redirecting to a different file (lets call it file2.asp) then try

```
strQS = Request.QueryString
If strQS <> "" Then strQS = "?" & strQS 
strURL = "file2.asp" & strQS
Response.Redirect strURL
Response.End
```

somewhere at the top of file.asp

Comment: Thanks Stephen, but I need to redirect to "file.asp", not a different file. Old product were id 100 and the new querystring for that product is 200... but google results, forums links, all of them are pointing to 100 so I need to tell them where is the product now.

Comment: got it - how many products are we talking about? Is there a formula that can express how the products id's are changing or is it random?

Comment: Hi Stephen. Maybe we are talking about 3 or 4 products. It is a specific problem, and I want to seize the moment to learn how to do it (redirect or rewrite) in case I have the same problem in the future. The product id is an entry in the db and usually I never change them because of seo. Thanks for your interst!

Comment: ok, I believe classic asp response.redirect issues a 302 redirect temporary, which is not so SEO friendly. You'd be wanting a method that issues a 301. redirect permanent.  As it's only a few products, this can be handled in the page, try this kind of code at the top of the page...  

`<%  
   Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"  
   Response.AddHeader "Location","http://www.whatever.com/file.asp?prodid=newprodid"  
   Response.End  
%>`  

Obviously, you'll need to add in some kind of IF statement for each product id.